# Crystal: how to increase the number of types an array can hold after instantiation

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm building a table of data. At first, the rows of this table are most easily filled by key / value so I use a hash

```
a = Hash(Int32, Symbol).new
a[1] = :one
```

Once that's done, it's more convenient to work with an array (I need to sort the data for example). Easy enough:

```
a.to_a # => [{1, :one}]
```

But now I'm discovering that for my formatter to work properly (multi-page table, using latex) things just make more sense if I can store another data type in that array, for example, a string. But it's too late! The type of the array is fixed; it won't admit a string.

```
a << "str" # => ERROR!
```

The solution I've come up with so far doesn't seem very elegant:

```
a = Hash(Int32, Symbol).new
a[1] = :one
arr = Array(String | Tuple(Int32, Symbol)).new
a.each do |k,v|
  arr << {k,v}
end
arr << "str" # no problem now
```

Is there a more "Crystal" / elegant way?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using a `Hash` in the first place? Key-Value pairs can also be stored directly in an array if you don't need lookup or duplicate checking. This would entirely avoid the problem of transforming to an array.

Comment: It would be nice to have a `collect` or `to_a(target)` method that would simply add all of the elements to the given target. That way you could do `a.to_a([] of String | Other)`.

Comment: @JohannesMüller Yes, in my case I need to do a lookup by key-value to fill the data. It's two-dimensional data being keyed one-dimensionally so I have to run through the columns, fill by key, then run through the rows and fill by key. A hash is the perfect tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `to_a` with [`as`](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/as.html) it can be used to cast to a "bigger" type as the docs call it

```
a = Hash(Int32, Symbol).new
a[1] = :one
arr = a.to_a.map { |x| x.as(String | Tuple(Int32, Symbol)) }
arr << "str" # [{1, :one}, "str"]
```

Comment: Your initial solution was already more elegant than this. Here you're creating an array just to immediately throw it away and in the process iterate through all the items twice. That's neither efficient nor elegant.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, this idea might be fewer lines of code, but that `to_a` is wasteful. Thanks for pointing that out!